# Stuck with table : alignement

Tags: layout, latex

I'm not satisfied with the layout and I thought about maybe some sort of table without borders or idk can u help me with it plz?

This is my code:

```
\begin{equation}
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \cos(x+2\pi)=\cos(x) \quad\text{and}\quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R},  \sin(x+2\pi)=\sin(x)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, \cos(x+\pi)=-\cos(x)\quad\text{and}\quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, sin(x+\pi)=-\sin(x)
\end{equation}
```

Comment: You should use the align environment from amsmath around your equations. It replaces the equation environment and allows to align simultaneously several equations.  You have to add alignment tabs (&) at the desired positions. Experiment until it fits your requirements. But we do not know what alignment you exactly want.

Comment: Well I'd like to write them kinda like a table with two colums but without any border so that each equation is aligned on 2 columns. Tell me if it's still not clear enough to you!

Comment: Math practice is to align the '=' signs of successive equations. But you have two equations per line and you can imagine to align both = signs, and/or to align the \forall(s), the 'and', etc... What is clear for nobody is the quality of the visual effect with these different alignments.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution with the align environment from amsmath.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\noindent Initial version with two equation environment
\begin{equation}
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \cos(x+2\pi)=\cos(x) \quad\text{and}\quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R},  \sin(x+2\pi)=\sin(x)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, \cos(x+\pi)=-\cos(x)\quad\text{and}\quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, sin(x+\pi)=-\sin(x)
\end{equation}

\medskip
\noindent With the align environment. = signs and 'and' are aligned
\begin{align}
  \forall x \in \mathbb{R},\, \cos(x+2\pi)&=\quad\cos(x) \quad\text{and}& \forall x \in \mathbb{R},\,  \sin(x+2\pi)=&\quad\sin(x)\\
  \forall x\in \mathbb{R},\, \cos(x+\pi)&=-\cos(x)\quad\text{and}& \forall x \in \mathbb{R},\, \sin(x+\pi)=&-\sin(x)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The equal signs and the `and' are aligned. I also added extra space after the = signs of the first line to align the sin/cos operators. This is unusual (and maybe forbidden by math standards), but it makes the symmetry of the expressions more obvious .

Disclaimer note : I am definitely **not** sure that it is compliant with the best mathematical typography recommendations. Experiment with other alignments.